# Extract multiple lines if match

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a command that outputs information about all DIMM slots in blocks like the following:

```
ID    SIZE TYPE
44    105  SMB_TYPE_MEMDEVICE (type 17) (memory device)

  Manufacturer: NO DIMM
  Serial Number: NO DIMM
  Asset Tag: NO DIMM
  Location Tag: P1-DIMMD1
  Part Number: NO DIMM

  Physical Memory Array: 43
  Memory Error Data: Not Supported
  Total Width: 0 bits
  Data Width: 0 bits
  Size: Not Populated
  Form Factor: 9 (DIMM)
  Set: None
  Rank: Unknown
  Memory Type: 2 (unknown)
  Flags: 0x4
        SMB_MDF_UNKNOWN (unknown)
  Speed: Unknown
  Configured Speed: Unknown
  Device Locator: P1-DIMMD1
  Bank Locator: P0_Node1_Channel0_Dimm0
  Minimum Voltage: 1.20V
  Maximum Voltage: 1.20V
  Configured Voltage: 1.20V
```

The blocks start with the `ID    SIZE TYPE` header and end with the configured voltage information.  The command outputs one of these blocks of data for each DIMM separated by a single blank line each.

---

I would like to be able to get the block of information for a specific DIMM slot based on the `Location Tag` field, but am unsure how to go about it.  I am pretty sure this can be done with `awk` but only know how to print the match `awk '/P1-DIMMD1/'` or the line prior to match `awk '/P1-DIMMD1/ {print a}{a=$0}'`

Does anyone know how I could extract this whole block of data if the `Location Tag` matches my search (`P1-DIMMD1`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will match the tag given in the tag variable:

```
awk -v tag=P1-DIMMD1 '/ID    SIZE TYPE/ { block = $0; output = 0; next } { block = block "\n" $0 } /Location Tag/ { output = ($0 ~ tag) } /Configured Voltage/ && output { print block }'
```

The AWK script is

```
/ID    SIZE TYPE/ {
  block = $0
  output = 0
  next
}

{ block = block "\n" $0 }

/Location Tag/ { output = ($0 ~ tag) }

/Configured Voltage/ && output { print block }
```

We accumulate a block in the `block` variable, and output it when we reach the end of the block if we saw the right tag in the process.

Answer (score 4):

You could [use ed](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html) ... **and** sed, man!

You have to *want* to use ed for this one, though, as ed wants to operate on a file, not as part of a pipeline.

1. `command > dimm-output`
2. `wanted=P1-DIMMD1`
3. `ed -s dimm-output <<< $'/Location Tag: '"$wanted"$'\n?^ID.*SIZE.*TYPE\n.,/Configured Voltage/p\nq\n' | sed 1,2d`

The `ed` command-string breaks down to four `\n`-separated commands:

1. search forwards, using `/`, for the text "Location Tag: " followed by the value of the `$wanted` variable
2. search backwards, using `?`, for the pattern: (start-of-line), "ID", anything, "SIZE", anything, "TYPE"
3. from that line (`.`), through (`,`) the next line that matches "Configured Voltage", print those lines (`p`)
4. quit ed: `q`

Because ed auto-prints the matching line when you search, I used `sed` here to delete those two lines.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @Stephen Kitts great answer, I wrote a little more general script to perform block matching when having a specified start and end pattern.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    pstart=ARGV[1];
    pstop=ARGV[2];
    pmatch=ARGV[3];
    ARGV[1]=ARGV[4];
    ARGC=2;
}
$0 ~ pstart { block = $0; output = 0; next }
{ block = block "\n" $0 }
$0 ~ pmatch { output = 1 }
$0 ~ pstop && output { print block; output = 0 }
```

Usage: `match_block START END MATCH [FILE]`

```
./match_block '^ID' 'Configured Voltage' 'Location Tag: P1-DIMMD1' f
```

or

```
command | ./match_block '^ID' 'Configured Voltage' 'Location Tag: P1-DIMMD1'
```

---

Thanks for suggesting writing this as an `awk` script directly. My original shell script was:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

[ -z "$4" ] && file="-" || file="$4"

awk \
  -v BLOCKSTART_PATTERN="$1" \
  -v BLOCKEND_PATTERN="$2" \
  -v BLOCKMATCH_PATTERN="$3" \
  '
  $0 ~ BLOCKSTART_PATTERN { block = $0; output = 0; next }
  { block = block "\n" $0 }
  $0 ~ BLOCKMATCH_PATTERN { output = 1 }
  $0 ~ BLOCKEND_PATTERN && output { print block; output = 0 }
  ' "$file"
```

Usage: `match_block START END MATCH [FILE]`.
If file is omitted, `stdin` will be used.

In your case:

```
command | ./match_block '^ID' 'Configured Voltage' 'Location Tag: P1-DIMMD1'
```

or

```
./match_block '^ID' 'Configured Voltage' 'Location Tag: P1-DIMMD1' file
```